# Assert Violation: LightningPrimitiveInputSimple is an invalid LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to test pretty simple example from [Data Binding in a Template](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/js-props-getter.html) in https://app.lwc.studio/

```html
<!-- helloBinding.html -->
<template>
    <p>Hello, {greeting}!</p>
    <lightning-input label="Name" value={greeting} onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input>
</template>
```

```js
// helloBinding.js
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class HelloBinding extends LightningElement {
  greeting = "World";

  handleChange(event) {
    this.greeting = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

But I am getting following:
[image]

Could someone help me why this issue occur?